# Как сделать Post запрос по нажатию на кнопку через функцию в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Есть кнопка, при клике на которую вызывается функция handleLike, которая изменяет переменную через хук useState. Затем нужно сделать запрос на сервер API и передать данные, только что обновленного объекта post.

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку и запуске функции handleLike
должно добавится поле reaction в объект post:
`setPost({ ...post, rate: newRate, reaction: params });`,
а уже потом должен уйти запрос на сервер. Но на сервер API уходит запрос без добавленного поля.
При этом setPost отрабатывает, но уже после того как уходит запрос на сервер API.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

const Liker = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({id: 123, rate: 1});

  const handleLike = (params) => {
    const newRate = post.rate + params;

    setPost({ ...post, rate: newRate, reaction: params });
    
    axios
      .post(`//localhost:3100/posts/`, {
        id: post.id,
        rate: post.rate,
        reaction: post.reaction,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
}

return (
    <div>
      <buttion onClick={() => handleLike(1)}></button>
    </div>  
  );
};

export default LikeButtons;
```

Answer (score 0):

react НЕ обновляет все по каждой строке. Т.е. выполнив setState это не значит, что на следующей строке state будет обновлён.
тут как минимум есть два варианта

1. получить post, обновить его в отельной переменой, и работать уже с этой переменной (кстати, обновить сам state, наверное, было бы логичней, после получения ответа)

```js
const Liker = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({id: 123, rate: 1});

  const handleLike = (params) => {
    const newRate = post.rate + params;
    
    const newPost = {
      ...post,
      rate: post.rate + params,
      reaction: params
    }

    axios
      .post(`//localhost:3100/posts/`, {
        id: newPost.id,
        rate: newPost.rate,
        reaction: newPost.reaction,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setPost(newPost);
      });
  }
  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleLike(1)}>send</button>
      </div>  
    );
};
```

2. в `handleLike` делать просто обновления state, а запрос поместить в `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
   axios
      .post(`//localhost:3100/posts/`, {
        id: post.id,
        rate: post.rate,
        reaction: post.reaction,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
}, [post.id]);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное Юрий. Выбрал 1-й вариант. В мое приложение подходит именно он. Ваше замечание про обновление post после получения ответа сервера оказалось очень ценным для меня.